# Ошибка при установке ширины колонки во время экспорта в Excel

Tags: c++, qt, excel

Моя часть кода экспорта в *Excel*:

```
void ExcelExportHelper::SetCellValue(int lineIndex, int columnIndex, QString value)
{
    if(!m_sheet ) {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "!m_sheet";
        return;
    }
    QAxObject *cell =  m_sheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", lineIndex, columnIndex);
    if(!cell ) {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "!cell";
        return;
    }
    cell->setProperty("Value",value);
}
```

Почему не работает?

```
cell->setProperty("Width",300);
```

ошибка :
`QAxObject::setProperty: Property "Width" invalid, read-only or does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    QAxObject *rangec = m_sheet->querySubObject( "Range(const QVariant&)",QVariant(QString("A:G")));
    // получаю указатель на строку
    QAxObject *razmer = rangec->querySubObject("Columns");
    // устанавливаю её размер.
    razmer->setProperty("ColumnWidth",80);
```

Comment: Странно... Пишете, что не разобрались, но ответ добавили (с моей подсказкой и по ширине столбца, и по оператору).

Comment: @vikttur на тот момент не разобрался. Сейчас уже получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Ширина столбца в *Excel* - от 0 до 255 знаков моношириного шрифта. 255 знаков - это около 1800 пикселей (коэффициент ~1,4).

Если нужно больше, можно объединить ячейки двух столбцов. Или без объединения - текст первого столбца перейдет на второй, если ячейка второго ничем не заполнена.

Comment: QAxObject::setProperty: Property "Width" invalid, read-only or does not exist

Comment: Когда выставляю cell->setProperty("Width",255);

Comment: и я меняю ячейку в самом Excel до любого размера в пикселях

Comment: А ширина задается в знаках моношириного шрифта (дополнил ответ). Для проверки установите меньше (например, 100). Возможно, оператор криво записан? В *VBA* так: `Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 100`. Еще догадка: что-то на листе правее не дает расшириться столбцу...

Comment: А как объединить ячейки?

Comment: С причиной разобрались? === Я не владею ни *С++*, ни *qt*. Оператор в *VBA* - `Merge`

Comment: нет пока не разобрался